# Exercise with differential in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $x,y,z,t$ be the standard coordinates for $\mathbb R^4$, and let $$f: S^3 \to \mathbb {CP}^1, \;\; f (x,y,z,t)=[x+iy:z+it].$$ I must show that $f $ is $C^\infty $ and find $df_p $ in coordinates; it is immediate that $f $ is $C^\infty $, because the inclusion of $S^3$ in $\mathbb R ^4/\{0\}\cong\mathbb C^2/\{0\}$ and the projection of $\mathbb C^2/\{0\}$ over $\mathbb {CP}^1$ are both $C^\infty $. However I am very confused about what "in coordinates" means; although I read several times my notes (and the page of Wikipedia) I couldn't apply the theoretical notions even to a simple problem. I think that this exercise could be explanatory; can you tell me a way to resolve it? Thanks a lot

Comment: I forgot to say that the point $p $ is the point of $S^3$ with coordinates $(1,0,0,0) $ in $\mathbb R^4$

Comment: So what is the easiest way to give local coordinates on $S^3$ near that point $p$? Or, even easier, can you find $d\tilde f_p$ where $\tilde f$ is an obvious (local) extension of $f$ to $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting in the second phrase, but I prefer not to go in that way. I think that the easiest way to give coordinates near $p$ is the stereographic projection of $S^3$, that we can even centre in $p$. However from here I don't see how to proceed. Thank you

Comment: You need coordinates on $\Bbb CP^1$ near $f(p)=[1,0]$. There are two standard charts; what is the chart containing this point? Then write $f$ in terms of these coordinate charts and proceed.

Comment: Ok, the point is that I know how to express $f$ as a function from $S^3$ to $\mathbb {CP^1}$, and I also have a proper parametrization $\phi $ of $S^3$ and a chart $\varphi $ for $\mathbb {CP^1}$ containing $f(p)$. With these premises, I could calculate the differential of $\varphi \circ f \circ \phi : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R $, but I don't understand what is the differental in the coordinates of $S^3$. Thank you

Comment: That's what they're asking you to compute — the derivative in local coordinates, i.e., the matrix for $df_p$ as a linear map $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$.